# Reusing variables across unit tests with testthat. Is there an acceptable practice to avoid recreating computationally expensive variables

Tags: r, testthat

I am creating an R package, where I have a function that creates an object and a function that makes a plot based on the object.

Example:

```
objA <- create_obj(sample)
plot_obj(objA)
```

I have some tests (using testthat) on the first function, eg:

```
objA <- create_obj(sample)
expect_value(length(objA), 10)
```

Now I want to test `plot_obj()`. I need an object to test it on, but creating a new `objA` is time consuming (seconds).

Can I make `objA` accessible to other tests (in other files) after the first tests have passed, so I can use it to test `plot_obj()` without recreating it?

(I suppose I could put `objA <- create_obj(sample)` in setup.R, but then I would use the function before having tested it).

Comment: Would it be an option to use `usethis::use_data(objA)` to create an `.rda` file of `objA` that will then reside in the `data`  folder of your package and that you can then easily use for tests and examples?

Comment: The problem with that would be, that if `create_obj()` changes, so it is incompatible with `plot_obj()` my tests for `plot_obj()` will not fail since it uses a stored version of objA.

Comment: That's true. Workaround 1: You could set up a `data-raw` script which creates `objA` based on `create_obj()`. I'm not sure of this can be automated, rerunning that script manually after each change is definitely not what you want. Workaround 2: create an unexported object `objA` in your package. If you update `create_obj()`, `objA` will be updated too.

Comment: Would there be any advantage to creating an unexported object and putting `objA <- create_obj(sample)` in `tests/testthat/setup.R`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the workaround I've settled on for now:

in ´tests/testthat/setup.R`:

```
try({
    objA <- create_obj(sample)
}, silent = TRUE)
```

This way, I'll still run my tests if `create_obj(sample)` crashes. I still create `objA` twice though: once in setup and once in the unit test of `create_obj`.